# ASIOSDK; Error when building mex file from hostsample.cpp

Tags: c++, matlab, build, mex, steinberg-asio

I'm writing a c++ file to build into mex, but I got the unsolved external symbol errors with asio function like "ASIOExit". I'm building in Matlab console with mex command.
I've put all headfiles and cppfiles from the AsioSDK. into one folder ad used -I to include that folder. What else do I need to include or link?

The 3 headfiles related to ASIO has already been added in include.

```
#include "asiosys.h" 
#include "asio.h"
#include "asiodrivers.h"
```

> Error using mex    Creating library hostsample.lib and object
>   hostsample.exp hostsample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol "long __cdecl ASIOInit(struct ASIODriverInfo *)"
>   (?ASIOInit@@YAJPEAUASIODriverInfo@@@Z) referenced in function
>   mexFunction hostsample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "long __cdecl ASIOExit(void)" (?ASIOExit@@YAJXZ) referenced in
>   function mexFunction hostsample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "long __cdecl ASIOStart(void)" (?ASIOStart@@YAJXZ)
>   referenced in function mexFunction hostsample.obj : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol "long __cdecl ASIOStop(void)"
>   (?ASIOStop@@YAJXZ) referenced in function mexFunction hostsample.obj :
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __cdecl
>   ASIOGetChannels(long *,long *)" (?ASIOGetChannels@@YAJPEAJ0@Z)
>   referenced in function "long __cdecl init_asio_static_data(struct
>   DriverInfo *)" (?init_asio_static_data@@YAJPEAUDriverInfo@@@Z)
>   hostsample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long
>   __cdecl ASIOGetLatencies(long *,long *)" (?ASIOGetLatencies@@YAJPEAJ0@Z) referenced in function "long __cdecl
>   create_asio_buffers(struct DriverInfo *)"
>   (?create_asio_buffers@@YAJPEAUDriverInfo@@@Z) hostsample.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __cdecl
>   ASIOGetBufferSize(long *,long *,long *,long *)"
>   (?ASIOGetBufferSize@@YAJPEAJ000@Z) referenced in function "long
>   __cdecl init_asio_static_data(struct DriverInfo *)" (?init_asio_static_data@@YAJPEAUDriverInfo@@@Z) hostsample.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __cdecl
>   ASIOGetSampleRate(double *)" (?ASIOGetSampleRate@@YAJPEAN@Z)
>   referenced in function "long __cdecl init_asio_static_data(struct
>   DriverInfo *)" (?init_asio_static_data@@YAJPEAUDriverInfo@@@Z)
>   hostsample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long
>   __cdecl ASIOSetSampleRate(double)" (?ASIOSetSampleRate@@YAJN@Z) referenced in function "long
>   __cdecl init_asio_static_data(struct DriverInfo *)" (?init_asio_static_data@@YAJPEAUDriverInfo@@@Z) hostsample.obj : error
>   LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long __cdecl
>   ASIOGetSamplePosition(struct ASIOSamples *,struct ASIOTimeStamp *)"
>   (?ASIOGetSamplePosition@@YAJPEAUASIOSamples@@PEAUASIOTimeStamp@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "void __cdecl bufferSwitch(long,long)"
>   (?bufferSwitch@@YAXJJ@Z) hostsample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "long __cdecl ASIOGetChannelInfo(struct
>   ASIOChannelInfo *)" (?ASIOGetChannelInfo@@YAJPEAUASIOChannelInfo@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "long __cdecl create_asio_buffers(struct
>   DriverInfo *)" (?create_asio_buffers@@YAJPEAUDriverInfo@@@Z)
>   hostsample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long
>   __cdecl ASIOCreateBuffers(struct ASIOBufferInfo *,long,long,struct ASIOCallbacks *)"
>   (?ASIOCreateBuffers@@YAJPEAUASIOBufferInfo@@JJPEAUASIOCallbacks@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "long __cdecl create_asio_buffers(struct
>   DriverInfo *)" (?create_asio_buffers@@YAJPEAUDriverInfo@@@Z)
>   hostsample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long
>   __cdecl ASIODisposeBuffers(void)" (?ASIODisposeBuffers@@YAJXZ) referenced in function mexFunction hostsample.obj : error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol "long __cdecl ASIOOutputReady(void)"
>   (?ASIOOutputReady@@YAJXZ) referenced in function "struct ASIOTime *
>   __cdecl bufferSwitchTimeInfo(struct ASIOTime *,long,long,class std::vector
>
> > ,class std::allocator > > >)"
> >     (?bufferSwitchTimeInfo@@YAPEAUASIOTime@@PEAU1@JJV?$vector@V?$vector@NV?$allocator@N@std@@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$vector@NV?$allocator@N@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@@Z)
> >     hostsample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
> >     __imp_timeGetTime referenced in function "struct ASIOTime * __cdecl bufferSwitchTimeInfo(struct ASIOTime *,long,long,class
> >     std::vector
> >     ,class std::allocator > > >)"
> >     (?bufferSwitchTimeInfo@@YAPEAUASIOTime@@PEAU1@JJV?$vector@V?$vector@NV?$allocator@N@std@@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$vector@NV?$allocator@N@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@@Z)
> >     hostsample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:
> >     void __cdecl AsioDrivers::removeCurrentDriver(void)"
> >     (?removeCurrentDriver@AsioDrivers@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function
> >     mexFunction hostsample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
> >     "bool __cdecl loadAsioDriver(char *)" (?loadAsioDriver@@YA_NPEAD@Z)
> >     referenced in function mexFunction hostsample.obj : error LNK2019:
> >     unresolved external symbol "struct ASIOTime * __cdecl
> >     bufferSwitchTimeInfo(struct ASIOTime *,long,long)"
> >     (?bufferSwitchTimeInfo@@YAPEAUASIOTime@@PEAU1@JJ@Z) referenced in
> >     function "void __cdecl bufferSwitch(long,long)"
> >     (?bufferSwitch@@YAXJJ@Z) hostsample.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
> >     external symbol "class AsioDrivers * asioDrivers"
> >     (?asioDrivers@@3PEAVAsioDrivers@@EA) referenced in function
> >     mexFunction hostsample.mexw64 : fatal error LNK1120: 19 unresolved
> >     externals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK looks like I haven't included all the cpp and h files in the solution.